# Show that $p(1)=2$ is not a subspace of of $P_3$ of real polynomials degree less than or equal to 3

Tags: linear-algebra

Now $ax^3+bx^2+c$ is a polynomial of degree $3$.
Now $P(1)=a+b+c=2$

And this is not a subspace because suppose I have $e+d+f=2$. Combining the two gives $(a+e)+(b+d)+(c+f)=2+2 \neq 2$

Is this a correct proof?

Comment: I think I know what you mean but your notation is off, because you seem to be using $x$ for two different things. You might say something like "let $p,q$ be two polynomials in this set, then $(p+q)(1)=p(1)+q(1)=2+2=4 \neq 2$".

Comment: I fixed it up to avoid notation confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The zero polynomial does not belong to the set of polynomials $p(x)$ such that $p(1)=2$.